# CSS text wrap vertical alignment

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, text, alignment, word-wrap

I'm using Bootstrap and I have a row with 6 grid columns. The first column is defined like this:

```html
<div class="hour-item col-sm-1 col-ms-1 col-sm-offset-3 col-ms-offset-3">
  <div class="hour-label" id="hour-label-1"></div>
  <div class="hour-value" id="hour-value-1"></div>
  <div class="hour-weekd" id="hour-weekd-1"></div>
</div>
```

The rest of the columns are pretty much the same, without the offset classes, and the inner div id numbering increments (-2, ... -6)

My objective here is to have the middle divs (hour-value-x) always aligned between them, a straight line. But the problem is that when text on the first inner div wraps to a second line, it pushes down the other two below it, and that column becomes vertically "misaligned" with the other columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been answered many times before on this site.

There are several ways this can be done but the best is to use some javascript to match the heights of the different inner divs.  Though the js that Wes Duff posted is good it will not cover all situations such as when a user resizes their browser.  Using something like [match height](http://brm.io/jquery-match-height/) would be better.

Comment: Guess I'm not that good at searching here, but I did try to find some answer addressing this. Going to take a look at your suggestion now, thanks.

Comment: Yea you would need to incorporate a window.resize event to re-run the autoHeight method.. Good call

Comment: This question comes up a lot because people are skipping learning CSS and just going to a framework, which is a shame.

Comment: Thanks for the useful insight, Christina.

Comment: matchHeight also worked out of the box, with the plus of maintaining the spacing. Good stuff. Hopefully its caveats won't surface, as I'm also using a fadeIn() and web font. Now just need to see if I can make the text align to the bottom/top.

Answer (score 1):

This is an age old issue. :?

Solution I have come up with is to use a JavaScript.

```
function autoHeight(ele){
  var height = 0;
  ele.each(function(){
    if($(this).height > height){
      height = $(this).height;
    }
  }).each(function() { $(this).height(height); });
```

Loop through and find the height for each element then assign the tallest height to each element.

```
<div class="hour-item col-sm-1 col-ms-1 col-sm-offset-3 col-ms-offset-3">
  <div class="hour-label" id="hour-label-1"></div>
  <div class="hour-value" id="hour-value-1"></div>
  <div class="hour-weekd" id="hour-weekd-1"></div>
</div>

//javascript (using jQuery) will look like
autoheight($('.hour_value'));
```

Comment: And me hoping CSS would be enough. Thanks for the quick reply. I implemented your suggestions, and it's definitely a step forward. The hour-label gets too close to hour-value. Gonna have to fine-tune this.

Comment: There may be something you can do with CSS3 and flexbox but it will not be cross-browser compliant  :)